# Custom Annotations in Java using array with different array object values

Tags: java, android

can anybody help me to write code for below  annotation?

> @Encryption( sensitiveTypeInfo={sensitiveTag=9, logHidingScheme='MASK', databaseHidingScheme='ENCRYPT', sensitiveTypeDescription='First name '})

**code snippet:**

```
@Documented
@Retention (RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target (ElementType.METHOD)
public @interface Encryption
{
    String[] sensitiveTypeInfo() ;

}
```

Comment: You forgot to ask a question.

Comment: How i can declare this tyoe of annotation in my code              
@Encryption(author={sensitiveTypeInfo={sensitiveTag=9, logHidingScheme='MASK', databaseHidingScheme='ENCRYPT', sensitiveTypeDescription='First name '}})                                                                                                        
                                                                                                                              
can  anybody help me to write code for above annotation?

Comment: Are you facing exceptions? What is the thing exactly what you want to achieve? If you provide a little more context, then this question will be much easier answerable.

Comment: @vijay your example in your comment is not valid Java

Comment: **Using above code snippet i can achieve only this  **           
 @Encryption( sensitiveTypeInfo={"1","2 "})                                                              
  But my requirement is i need a custom attributes/values in Annotation like below                                                                                                                  
@Encryption( sensitiveTypeInfo={sensitiveTag=9, logHidingScheme='MASK', databaseHidingScheme='ENCRYPT', sensitiveTypeDescription='First name '})         how i can  achieve  this?

Comment: Short answer: you can't, since it's not valid Java. Long answer: you can achieve something similar by embedding annotations within your annotation, similar to how (for instance) JPA does these things: https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/Table.html#uniqueConstraints--

Comment: Stop adding information as comments, update your question instead.

Answer (score 1):

Based on your comments you should probably try a solution with nested annotations:

```
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target(ElementType.METHOD)
public @interface A
{
  String author();
  B[] nested();
}

@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target(ElementType.METHOD)
public @interface B
{
  String label();

  C[] moreNested();
}

@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target(ElementType.METHOD)
public @interface C
{
  int value();
}
```

You can then do the following:

```
@A(author="Vijay", nested={
   @B(label="First", moreNested=@C(5)),
   @B(label="Second", moreNested={@C(6), @C(7)})
})
```